# Laravel best way of using setlocale with carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am new to the laravel framework and OOP. I am building a small webapp.

One of the things what comes back every time on the website is the date of today. To generate the date of today I use Carbon like so

`{{ carbon\carbon::today()->formatLocalized(' %d %B %Y') }}` in my view.

That works fine and gives me back the following: "1 March 2017". Because my application is suppose to be in dutch i've searched for a function to set the dates to dutch. I've found this: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');` What works just fine except I have to add it to every controller method I use for the views where I need the date.

Is there a better/cleaner solution for this? Like somewhere I can set it global.

Comment: in `config/app.php` you can set a locale and a timezone.

Comment: It doesn't work when I change the default `en` to `nl` so I guess that is not supported for the dutch lang

Comment: Are you trying "NL_nl" or just "nl" ?

Comment: Both,   `'locale' => 'NL_nl',`,     `'locale' => 'nl',` and  also  ` 'locale' => 'nl_NL',`. Both for locale as fallback_locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

1) a BaseController class, in the __construct() you can use setlocale(), next you derive every localized controller from the BaseController class.
2) in a middleware

Dont know if your locale can change per request (i.e. ?locale=xx), is stored on authenticad user or others way, but the 2 methods above should works with fixed or changing locale.

I use the middleware way:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    $locale = false;
    if(Auth::user()){
        $locale = Auth::user()->locale;
    }elseif(session()->has('locale')) {
        $locale = session('locale');
    }elseif($request->has('locale')) {
        $locale = request('locale');
    }
    if($locale && array_key_exists($locale, config('app.locales'))) {
        app()->setLocale($locale);
        setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: So I tried to use the first option. In the default controller I've added a `__construct` method and within it I've added the code. It seems to work. Is this a clean way?

Comment: if you use only controller for resolve routes in wich you want localized dates is a clean way

Comment: The first option is not clean. The second is kinda, but you really should try to fix it through app config.